# pythonのコード例が理解できない

Tags: python

2.3日前にプログラミングを始めたばかりです。独学プログラマーという本を見ながら学んでます。
コードを書くときに1行目に

```
#http://tinyurl.com/hhwqva2
```

とあるのですが、何個かコードの例を見ているとこのcomの後のコードがそれぞれ違ったのですがなぜでしょうか、またそのコード例の見つけ方を教えて欲しいです。

Comment: 恐らく書籍の内容に関わるサンブルを公開しているページのURLで、短縮URLサービスを利用しているため末尾の文字列が変わります。

Comment: 参考: [dokupro-link.pdf](http://web-cache.stream.ne.jp/www11/nikkeibpw/com/sp/dokupro-link.pdf)

Comment: ありがとうございます！

Answer (score 2):

単なるコメントでしょう。サンプルと同じコードを掲載しているサイトのURL。

> comの後のコードがそれぞれ違った

サンプルが異なれば、それぞれ別の掲載アドレスを指しているということです。